# Unable to scrape few details in BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am using BeautifulSoup to scrpe the data , everything is working in my code except one single thing,and that is price. I am trying to scrape a real estate website and unable to scrape the price.Website is "https://www.proptiger.com/all-projects"

below are my codes:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import json
import io
url = "https://www.proptiger.com/all-projects"
# for all pages https://www.proptiger.com/all-projects?page=2
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
container = soup.find_all("section", {"class":"project-card-main-wrapper"})  
print(len(container))

newFile = "Prop_Data.csv"
f = open(newFile, "w", encoding = "utf-8")
Headers = "Project, Url, City, Builder, Price\n"
f.write(Headers)
#f.close()

for i in container:
    contain = i.find_all("div", {"class":"proj-name"})
    project_name = contain[0]['title']
    url2 = i.div['data-url']
    url1 = "https://www.proptiger.com"
    url = url1+url2
    get_city = i.find_all("span", {"itemprop":"address"})#or by div, {"class":"loc"}
    city  = get_city[0]["title"]# or by getcity.text
    builder = i.find_all("div", {"class":"projectBuilder put-ellipsis"})
    bName = builder[0].text
    price = i.find_all("div", {"class":"project-price"})
    pricereal = price[0].text#not able to print the print says list out of index
    print(pricereal)
    #f.write("{}".format(project_name) +",{}".format(url)+",{}".format(city)+",{}".format(bName)+"\n")
 #f.close()
```

now whenever i run this code it says list out of range.

below is the html of the price.:

```js
<div class="project-price" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/PriceSpecification"><span itemprop="minPrice">₹ 32.4 L</span><span itemprop="maxPrice">- ₹ 88.0 L</span>
            <!-- -if(project.avgPricePerUnitArea)div.text-right.price-perunit &#8377;  / sq ft-->
        </div>
```

i want the min price and max price, so i do text and get the price for 56=-6 items and then list out of range. Can someone what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't get the price because it is within javascript. Don't get confused to see that all the other items are getting printed but why price are not. So to get around that you can use selenium in combination with BeautifulSoup.

I have used here the necessary portion of the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.proptiger.com/all-projects")
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
driver.quit()

for item in soup.find_all("section", {"class":"project-card-main-wrapper"}):
    price = item.select(".project-price")[0].text if item.select(".project-price") else ""
    print(price)
```

Partial results:

```
₹ 32.4 L- ₹ 88.0 L
₹ 33.6 L- ₹ 51.0 L
₹ 62.0 L- ₹ 1.25 Cr
₹ 49.9 L- ₹ 1.32 Cr
₹ 35.0 L- ₹ 50.0 L
```

To make things clearer, please see below:

```
>>> import requests
>>> link = "https://www.proptiger.com/all-projects"
>>> page = requests.get(link).text
>>> 'Umang Premiere' in page
True
>>> '₹ 35.0 L' in page
False
>>>
```

I did it in python IDE. As you can see the product name is found but the price are not. It is because of javascript. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: hi, is it possible to do it in my codes, like what if i want it with using beautifulSoup only?

Comment: As far my knowledge goes: No. It's not possible. BeautifulSoup is unable to deal with dynamically generated items. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'll try it with selenium then..Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Because one of the projects(Godrej Emerald) has a price on request, and therefore no price value.

Answer (score 1):

You will get that error when you are scraping information that is not available.  If you are finding the price and there's no value displayed for a particular item, it will display an error and break the code.  It's breaking because your code is saying there's something there, when there really isn't.

The way to get around this is with a try-except statement.

```
try:
    pricereal = price[0].tex
except:
    pricereal = "n/a"
```

Comment: i tried it with try and except but it is not working... and i am still wondering why!

Comment: It looks Shahin got it right -- the culprit was JavaScript.  I personally use Selenium for every project, it's good to use for times like this and also to keep tabs on what and where your scraping from.